# Puppet: making .yaml dependent on .pp

Tags: puppet, require

I am trying to install docker onto a disk other than system on my CentOS 7.2 VM. I create a directory and a symlink first with the required target in my .pp, and then want to install docker using yaml.

```
file { '/data/docker-latest':
    ensure => 'directory',
}

file { '/var/lib/docker-latest':
    ensure => 'link',
    target => '/data/docker-latest',
    require =>  File['/data/docker-latest'],
}
```

For it to work, the directory and the symlink need to be created before the .yaml kicks in:

```
packages: 
  docker-latest: 
    ensure: installed 
services: 
  docker-latest:
    ensure: running
```

But there is no guarantee like this. Is there a way I can make my .yaml code to `require => File['/var/lib/docker-latest']`?

Or am I better off installing and running docker inside `.pp`?

Comment: You are running this Puppet manifest and Docker independently in parallel, correct? If you are orchestrating this from outside Puppet, then you can control the flow from there also.

Comment: Running them in parallel, but inside puppet.

Comment: Then where/what is the Puppet resource/code for running Docker that you are using?